# Maven compilation with multiple 3rd party libraries for OSGi deployment

Tags: maven, pom.xml, aem

I'm beginner in Maven and I want to create .jar file from my .java with multiple 3rd party libraries. I have over 32 libs that I use in my project and I need to compile the project so I can use it in CQ5 OSGi. I have this in my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>info.hartmann.dfs</groupId>
  <artifactId>dfs-connection-handler</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>DFS connection handler</name>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\Users\302104\workspace\DFS\src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\Users\302104\workspace\lib</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <directory>C:\Users\302104\workspace\DFS\target</directory>
    <finalName>dfs-connection-handler-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-sling-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-bundle</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <slingUrl>http://localhost:4502/system/console</slingUrl>
        <user>user</user>
        <password>password</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wrap-my-dependency</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wrap</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <wrapImportPackage>;</wrapImportPackage>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <export-package>info.hartmann.dfs</export-package>
            <import-package>
                java.util.List;resolution=optional,
                com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.*;resolution=optional,
                com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.content.*;resolution=optional,
                com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.profiles.*;resolution=optional,
                com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel.core.query.*;resolution=optional,
                com.emc.documentum.fs.rt.context.*;resolution=optional,
                com.emc.documentum.fs.services.core.client.*;resolution=optional,
                *
            </import-package>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I have almost no idea what I'm doing with this pom.xml so any help would be nice.

BTW how can I compile that .java file using marks like

```
@Service(DfsHandler.class)
@Component(label = "DFS Connection Handler", immediate = true, metatype = true)
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to start would be the [developing with maven](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/developing/developmenttools/developing-with-maven.html) page on the [dev.day.com](http://dev.day.com/) site.  This has lots of information to get you started.

If the 32 libraries you have are in a maven repository, you should reference them via [dependency](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) entries in the POM.  If the dependencies are not in maven, you can reference them with a systemPath in a dependency entry like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
    <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/swingx-0.9.3.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively, [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/) describes how to use maven to add those libraries to your local repository.

If you are able to, it is best to lay your projects out according to [maven standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) to avoid having to configure lots of paths.  At the very least configure paths to be relative to the project, rather than specific to your machine.  For example, instead of using `C:\Users\302104\workspace\DFS\src`, just use `src`.

You can process the @Service & @Component annotations using the [Apache Felix SCR maven](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin.html) plugin. :

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>scr</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This plugin will generate the metadata that is added to your bundle that will register your service with the Felix OSGi runtime.

You'll also need the SCR annotations dependency in your project:

```
<dependency>
  <!-- scr annotations - for generating component descriptors only -->
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This [presentation on SCR](http://www.pro-vision.de/content/medialib/pro-vision/production/adaptto/2012/adaptto2012-lightning-scr-annotations-for-fun-and-profit-mike-pf/_jcr_content/renditions/rendition.file/adaptto2012-lightning-scr-annotations-for-fun-and-profit-mike-pfaff.pdf) should give you a good introduction to their use.  Also, I have a simple working example in [this github repo](https://github.com/cpilsworth/osgi-maven-bundle-dependency).

Comment: I've updated the answer above.  You would not normally put dependencies in src/main/resources.  This location is usually used for static assets / config files etc.   However, if you wish to keep this location, then update the systemPath to something like: `<systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swingx-0.9.3.jar</systemPath>`

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I'm able to compile it with all libraries but I still get error because of \@Service and \@Component. I've added the Apache Felix SCR maven plugin to <plugins> section in <build> but it's still same.

Comment: The SCR annotations dependency is also required to compile the project using the annotations.  I've added the details to the answer.

Comment: I've found the dependency section at Apache Felix SCR maven plugin site and added it to the pom.xml but it still doesn't work... I stil get these errors: http://pastebucket.com/16231 here is my pom.xml: http://pastebucket.com/16232

Comment: What's at Hander.java lines 32/33?

Comment: 32: \@Service(MyService.class) 33: \@Component(label = "My Service", immediate = true, metatype = true) (without the backslashes)

Comment: And you've imported:
`import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;`

Comment: Well... I have imported it now and it works!(again :D) But now there is another problem... The OSGI-INF folder isn't in the compiled .jar package. It's just in target/scr-plugin-generated. Is it possible to add it automatically to .jar package?

Comment: That might be best as another question.  Please accept this answer if it addressed your question.